# Struct in Vector, a vector include 8000 members

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have some problem building a 8000 rows vector. Each row is a struct including 5 columns. I am not sure what the C++ have no response even error message... it just says "The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3b48) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x309c) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[13048] Branch Filter Vector.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a)."

My code will be

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct branch {
    long int FromBusNum;
    string FromBusName;
    double FromBusVoltage;
    long int ToBusNum;
    string ToBusName; 
    ;



};


int main()
{
  vector<branch> myBranch(8000);
  ifstream infile;
  long int x1;
    string x2;
    double x3;
    long int x4;
    string x5; 
    ;

  int num = 0; // num must start at 0

   //infile.open("Data.txt");
     if(infile.fail()) // checks to see if file opended 
    { 
      cout << "error" << endl; 
      return 1; // no point continuing if the file didn't open...
    } 
     string dummyLine; //do not read in the first line 
     getline(infile, dummyLine);

       while(!infile.eof()) // reads file to end of *file*, not line
      { 


             myBranch.push_back(branch());


             infile>>x1 >> x2 >> x3 >> x4
                >> x5  ;

            myBranch[num].FromBusNum = x1;
            myBranch[num].FromBusName = x2;
            myBranch[num].FromBusVoltage = x3;
            myBranch[num].ToBusNum = x4;
            myBranch[num].ToBusName = x5;

         ++num; // go to the next number


      } 
  infile.close(); 

  ofstream fout("valency.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        fout/*<<myBranch[i].FromBusNum<<"\t"
        <<myBranch[i].FromBusName<<endl;

    fout.close();

  system("pause");
  return 0; // everything went right.

}
```

Not sure where the problem appears... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct error code, accord to Microsoft, 0xc000013a means you pressed CTRL-C... ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson THis is the error message after I close the pop up window... So I don't think it caused by my code..

Comment: Well, I took your code, compiled it, made a file with 8000 lines of `1 A 3.3 8 B`, and it worked just fine. So either it's something in your file, or something different between g++ and whatever compiler you are using...

Comment: Maybe processing `8000` rows takes longer on your system then you expect and it is not an error, but you program ist still processing the file when you close it. Anyway to detect those issues you should use the debugger and e.g. instead of closing the program you would pause its execution to check where it currently is.

Comment: On my system, in 32-bit mode, with no optimisation, it takes 0.02s, so Windows would have to be ridicolously mush slower than my system for that to be the case.

Comment: However, if you are reading 8000 lines exactly, it will crash because of the double last line, since eof is not true untile you've "tried to go past end of file", rather than "when you've read all the way up to and including the last line".

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks for your explaination. After I wait for 2 mins, there is a error     "Unhandled exception at 0x7672c41f (KernelBase.dll) in Branch Filter Vector.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0032f318.."

Comment: When you do `vector<branch> myBranch(8000);` you construct a vector with 8000 elements. Then when you do `myBranch.push_back(branch());` you are adding __additional__ elements to the end. Either create the vector with the desired size or leave it empty and do your `push_back()`, not both.

Comment: Well, I removed the `push_back` in the beginning of your loop, fixed up the "double last line", and it all runs fine on my system - and I put some larger strings in (26 characters for both sides). I can't make it go wrong. Sounds like your system is going into an infinite loop allocating stuff. I read it all in, and output to a new file and the only difference is the missing first line from the input file.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I delete the myBranch.push_back(branch()). And output the "num" in each iteration. "num" keep increasing to 8000 and even increasing to 20,000+. You are exactly right. Seems like my code doesn't recognize EOF of the file! Do you know how I can fix it?

Comment: Your code is invalid, you have unterminated comment.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code has some "broken bits". I first fixed up the "don't push back in the loop", and as a common "this is how you should do it", moved the `infile >> x1 >> ...` into the while-condition. This has a few benefits:

1. It doesn't run the loop once too many (because you read the last complete line and then run one more iteration because EOF is only detected when the code tries to read PAST the end of file).
2. If data fails to be read correctly (e.g. there are letters in something that is supposed to be a number), the code stops reading data. This is perhaps not a fantastic solution, but it's better than "looping forever", which is the case if you ONLY detect EOF, because when trying to read something that is in error, the processing doesn't progress - it just stops reading at that point, and all other input values are skipped over. This tends to bring on an endless loop, because no more reading happens and EOF is never reached. I suspect this is why the 20000+ number is reached in the comment - there is an error of some sort in the input text (space in a string so that the next input is out of synch, for example).
3. It is a little shorter/less complex (saves code-space). This is indeed a minor thing, but not a drawback by any means.

I have only made enough to make it work as I expect it should, so there may still be small problems in the code. For example, reading data from a file should check more thoroughly for errors than this does, for example by reading an entire line and then splitting it, with error checking for each entry (relates to point 2 above, that I wrote after I wrote this sentence). If you expect to know how many lines there are in a file, you may also want to CHECK that `num` doesn't got over this, and error out if it does.

This is the code I came up with:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct branch {
    long int FromBusNum;
    string FromBusName;
    double FromBusVoltage;
    long int ToBusNum;
    string ToBusName; 
};


int main()
{
    vector<branch> myBranch(8000);
    ifstream infile;
    long int x1;
    string x2;
    double x3;
    long int x4;
    string x5; 

    int num = 0; // num must start at 0

    infile.open("Data.txt");
    if(infile.fail()) // checks to see if file opended 
    { 
    cout << "error" << endl; 
    return 1; // no point continuing if the file didn't open...
    } 
    string dummyLine; //do not read in the first line 
    getline(infile, dummyLine);

    while(infile>>x1 >> x2 >> x3 >> x4 >> x5) // reads file to end of *file*, not line
    { 
    myBranch[num].FromBusNum = x1;
    myBranch[num].FromBusName = x2;
    myBranch[num].FromBusVoltage = x3;
    myBranch[num].ToBusNum = x4;
    myBranch[num].ToBusName = x5;

    ++num; // go to the next number
    } 
    infile.close(); 

    ofstream fout("data.out");
    if (fout.fail())
    {
    cout << "Error on outfile" << endl;
    return 2;
    }
    for(auto v : myBranch)
    {
    fout << v.FromBusNum  << " "
         << v.FromBusName << " "
         << v.FromBusVoltage << " "
         << v.ToBusNum << " " 
         << v.ToBusName << endl;

    }
    cout << "num=" << num << endl;

    return 0; // everything went right.
}
```

The data I run can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/Leporacanthicus/1c25dd0f9b00d090f1a5